# Javascript Word and characterCount validation

Tags: javascript, validation, counter

I have a textarea `$.questionField` where the user needs to enter at least 5 words and 20 characters. when this minimum is reached, the submit button becomes active. this works.

there is also a word `$.wordCounter` and character `$.characterCounter` counter that shows the user the remaining words/characters. this only partially works:

only the first word /character counter changes color to green when the threshold has been reached. i assume the if code structure below needs to be amended/bloated up catching both cases (if either the words or the characters' limit has been reached first).

is there no saner way to achieve this with javascript (or underscore)?

```
$.questionField.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    var words = $.questionField.value.split(" ").length;
    var characters = $.questionField.value.replace(/[^A-Z]/gi, "").length;
    console.log("characters " + characters);
    if (words > 5 && characters > 20) {
        if (OS_IOS) {
            $.submitIconSubmitPage.touchEnabled = true;
            $.submitIconSubmitPage.color = "green";
        }
    } else if (words <= 5 || characters <= 20){
                if (words <=5) {
                    $.wordCounter.color = "red";
                    $.wordCounter.text = 5 - words;
                } else {
                    $.wordCounter.color = "green";
                }
                if (characters <=20) {
                    $.characterCounter.color = "red";
                    $.characterCounter.text = 20 - characters;
                } else {
                    $.characterCounter.color = "green";
                }

            if (OS_IOS) {
                $.submitIconSubmitPage.touchEnabled = false;
                $.submitIconSubmitPage.color = "red";
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason your variables start with `$.`

Comment: would be helpful to have a fiddlejs link to try some options

Comment: im using alloy titanium. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Concepts the $. refers to the UI elements. ($.counter is a text label for instance)

Comment: here's a start http://jsfiddle.net/rb8rnmb1/

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to validate based on upper case character, or word count, and set the color of the characters depending on the length?

Using jQuery I would have done something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/b0eunmpz/3/). But it might not fit your needs if you don't use jQuery.

```
$('#myInput').on('keyup', function(event){
    var val = $('#myInput').val().trim(),
        numWords = val.split(' ').length,
        numCharacter = val.replace(/\s/g, '').length;

    $('.characterCounter').text(20-numCharacter + ' characters remaining.');
    $('.wordCounter').text(5 - numWords + ' words remaining.');

    if(numWords >= 5 || numCharacter >= 20){
        $('#myInput').addClass('valid');
        $('#mySubmit').addClass('valid');
        $('.remaining').hide();
    } else {
        $('.remaining').show();
        $('#myInput').removeClass('valid');
        $('#mySubmit').removeClass('valid');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. yes, the color of the counters are first red and when the thresholds are met, they turn green (and stop at 0). the character counter is case-insensitive.  adding jquery is not an option for this case.

Answer (score 0):

It can be tidied up a fair bit, but essentially you want something like:

```
question.on('keyup', function(){
    var words = question.val().split(/\s*/).length;
    var characters = question.val().toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w]/g, '').length;

    wordCount.text(words);
    characterCount.text(characters);

    wordCount.toggleClass('red', words < 5);
    characterCount.toggleClass('red', characters < 20);

    if(words >= 5 && characters >= 20) {
        submit.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Here's a JSfiddle showing it in action. https://jsfiddle.net/mwta17ph/ You will need to add in your OS_IOS work though.